# Get recently uploaded documents in document library including files added to any folders using REST API

Tags: 2013, document-library, rest, csom

I have a document library which may have folders in it. I want to get the most recently uploaded files (say latest 10 files) using REST API, irrespective of which folders they are uploaded to.

I can get the latest files in root folder by using below URL.

`http://<SERVER>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/<DOCUMENT LIBRARY>')/files?$select=Name,TimeCreated&$orderby=TimeCreated%20desc`

But it does not include any files uploaded to folders in the document library.

How can I achieve this? I am open to using client object model also.

Comment: My account is blocked so help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below REST endpoint:

```
http://<SERVER>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?
$filter=ContentType eq 'Document'
&$select=Title,FileLeafRef,Created,EncodedAbsUrl
&$orderby=Created desc&$top=10
```

This will give you latest 10 uploaded documents along with the document's title, name, absolute url as well as created date. This assumes that you know the list name.

Comment: you can also specify filter as `$filter=ContentType ne 'Folder'` which will exclude the folders